# Gerrit - how to fork repository?

Tags: gerrit

How can I fork a repository on Gerrit, so that the forked repository retains the change list history of the forked-from project?

I don't mean to fork from one Gerrit instance to another. Just within one Gerrit instance, rather than creating a new repository and submitting all contents of the other project in one big CL, actually forking/cloning that repository to retain a common CL history

Answer (score 3):

Gerrit doesn't have the "concept" of "fork". As you have said, you can create a new repository and push all the commits/tags of the original one to it, or you can simply create a new branch in the original repository.

Comment: but then how can I preserve the history in the new repository, so that I can show the 'blame' view and get to the corresponding changelists (that were merged into the original repository)?

Comment: If you push all commits/tags you'll preserve the "blame" (committers) but you won't have the changes of the original repository. The best solution is to create a new branch in the original repository.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to "fork" the repo in / with Gerrit.

Go to Gerrit and create the new repository. Set "Create initial empty commit" to "false", otherwise copying the master branch will fail.

Then on the console:

```
git clone --mirror ssh://<username>@<url>:<port>/<name_of_old_repository> <name_of_new_repository>
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin ssh://<username>@<url>:<port>/<name_of_new_repository>
git push origin --all
git push --tags
```